# Creating new files with Lua I/O functions

Tags: io, lua, text-files

I'm starting to learn about the io. functions, and am trying to implement them in my code.  I've searched for the answer to this and nothing seems to give a clear cut yes or no, or at least I don't see one.  I'm hoping someone here will know the answer and be able to help with this.

I'm wanting to create a text file that I can write to as time progresses.  It'll basically be a log to which I'll be appending lines of output.  Apparently io.open("textfile.txt") does not create the file, or so it appears.

Is there a way to create a text file in Lua that can later be accessed with io.read/write?  Additionally, do I need to call io.close() before opening or creating a new text file?  I appreciate any help given.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to open the file for *writing* as follows: `f=io.open("textfile.txt","w")`. Then use `f:write()` to write stuff to it. When finished writing, call `f:close()`.

Comment: You should state whether you're opening it for read or write with the second parameter to `io.open("filename", "w")`. The flags have the same meaning as those for `fopen`.