# Where "io.open" saves the file if it doesn't exist yet?

Tags: file, io, lua

I could find out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7277456/2320153), how can I create a new file with pure Lua code. The next snippet should do it theoretically:

```
file = io.open("test.txt", "w")
file:write("Hello World")
file:close()
```

However, I can't find the created file in the folder of the source code file. Where does it save the file - if it even creates a new one?

If not, what's the way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will use the processes current working directory (CWD) which is going to wherever your shell/environment was when you ran the script.

Comment: It took me a while to find it out, because I was a bit confused, but it's clear now. I use LÖVE, so it was the directory of LÖVE. Thanks!